# Create dll of ClassLibrary and WebForms Code behind ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, webforms

I have a project contains a classLibrary and webapplication now what I want is to use this project in another project means I want to add this entire project to another project as dll so developer of newer project cant use, update and see my code they just add in their project and simply use them without knowing whats going on in these dll. I am new to this can someone help me on this. I just to reuse code of webform's code behind and classlibrary .cs files code class which are used and called in webform's code behind.

Comment: I am new at this please don't vote down me on this

Comment: If you are downvoted then not because you are new, but because of the quality of your question. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Currently your question is quite broad. Did you try to google for some guidance on how to create a dll? If not, then please do that first. If you read something and you are stuck, then please come back and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a class library,
it compiles into a dll.

you can explore the file-system's BIN folder of your project,
and see the dll there after a project build.

What you want to do is take that dll,
and add it as a reference to another project.
Note: You may need to include a using [dll namespace] statement if you want to access
the dll objects / functions without explicitly writing it every time.

I created a mini sample,
here are some screen shots that should guide you through the process.
I'm using VS 2010, but it should be similar 2012 / 2013.

[image: Create a class libary project]
[image: build it, look at the namespace, we'll use it later]
[image: Open the filesystem folder]
[image: See the created dll file]
[image: create a web site]
[image: add a new reference]
[image: go to the dll path]
[image: include the namespace and you should be able to use it]

Comment: Thanks that's a very good answer it worked great for classLiabrary but can you please tell me how to hide code of webforms means PageName.aspx.cs file can I do this or is there any other way around of doing it please explain on this then I will mark this as answer please thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand,

Some code will always be visible, and that's the code you write, and some code will be referenced, in this case it's the dll you compiled out of the class libary project.

When you write a web app, the *.cs file which contains server functionality (I.e. code behind), and is used by the web app.
The *.cs file can contain code (hard coded) and it can contain code which reference dlls, but the cs file will exist.

Can you explain further what is the exact need?